# how to find the authentication used on a website

Tags: python, http, authentication, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I've been reading about beautifulSoup, http headers, authentication, cookies and something about mechanize.

I'm trying to scrape my favorite art websites with python. Like deviant art which I found a scraper for. Right now I'm trying to login but the basic authentication code examples I try don't work.

So question, How do I find out what type of authentication a site uses so that I know I'm trying to login the correct way? Including things like valid user-agents when they try to block bots.

Bear with my ignorance as I'm new to HTTP, python, and scraping.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that any of the sites you are interested in use basic auth. You will need a library like mechanize that manages cookies and you will need to submit the login information to the site's login page.

Comment: Thanks I was starting to believe I wasn't going to get any help. I've read about mechanize a little but it's description left me confused so I didn't even bother with it. Is there a tutorial on how I can use the python version of Mechanize for my purposes?

Comment: I recommend scraperwiki.com, they have tutorials and there's other people's python+mechanize scrapers for you to look at.